# tableview cell how do we resize cell in swift along with image and label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image] when we have a lable and image in tableview cell how do we resize cell in swift or lable as per the text  in the Last cell(in picture) there  are some more lines of text but text is cutting off how we resolve it

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, what links you went to? Please share. Because it has been asked several times.

Comment: tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension i tried this but its working only for lable but i have image too . image is getting wrapped not showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Give constrain to your lable hight greater equal and put line to 0.**

```
var pickheight: CGFloat = 0.0
```

**Write this line in**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableTrip.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Method for increase tableview cell .**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

     pickheight = self.findHeightForText("Pass your text here like array value as String ", havingWidth: self.view.frame.size.width - 116, andFont: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)).height

     return "YOUR_DEFALUT_CELL_SIZE" + pickheight
}
```

**Method for find text hight for cell..**
[image: Its my label constrain ...]

```
func findHeightForText(text: String, havingWidth widthValue: CGFloat, andFont font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        var size = CGSizeZero
        if text.isEmpty == false {
            let frame = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFloat.max), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
            size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, ceil(frame.size.height))
        }
        return size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. set **top,bottom,leading,trailing** constraints for your label
2. set **Attribute Inspector->lines** to 0
3. set **tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension** in **viewDidLoad()** method

Answer (score 0):

All you really have to do is:

1. Use Auto Layout when creating your table view cells.
2. Set the table view rowHeight to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension.**
3. Set the **estimatedRowHeight** or implement the height estimation delegate method.

   `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

   `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200  // Set maximum height needed for the table row`

The trick to getting Auto Layout to work on a UITableViewCell is to **ensure you have constraints to pin each subview on all sides** — that is, each subview should have leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints. Then, the intrinsic height of the subviews will be used to dictate the height of each cell.

Please, Read this article for details and working sample: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells