# How to adjust label height and width in custom tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a expandable tableView, in which when i expand a section, than there are three cell. On firth Cell there is only name and in second cell. It have a big content. Now I want to auto adjust this label height and width according to content.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let dataArrayTblView = dataArrayForTableView
        let titleName = dataArrayTblView.valueForKey("name")
        let dueDate = dataArrayTblView.valueForKey("deadlinedate")
        let description = dataArrayTblView.valueForKey("description")

        cell.titleLabel.text = titleName[indexPath.row] as AnyObject! as! String!
        cell.dueDateLabel.text = dueDate[indexPath.row] as? String
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = description[indexPath.row] as? String

        cell.descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()


        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
    }
```

**But not getting complete content**

[image]

Comment: I am not getting my complete description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888512/tableview-cell-how-do-we-resize-cell-in-swift-along-with-image-and-label/39888662#39888662

Comment: I am not using AutoLayout.

Comment: try this cell.descriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this. It will automatically adjust the height of the row for you. If it is not working, then you have something wrong with your constraints inside your storyboard.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: after using this I have lost my Due Date and Description cell

Comment: how many rows do you have? From your answer, I'm guessing you are doing all wrong for table view.

Comment: I have only Three rows

Comment: For first and second row there is only one line label

Comment: But for third row I have a label . And i want to auto adjust it according to content, Content I am getting from API

Answer (score 0):

Use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to adjust height of row. Calculate 
size of string with `boundingRectWithSize` this method. example:

Try This:

```
if let YOUR_STRING:NSString = str as NSString? {
let sizeOfString = ns_str.boundingRectWithSize(
                                 CGSizeMake(self.titleLabel.frame.size.width, CGFloat.infinity),options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,   attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: lbl.font], context: nil).size
}
```

Comment: What value to be return?

Comment: This method will return CGRect and you just return sizeOfString.height because at last I am getting is CGSize value with **.size**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as row height something like,

```
  // this should be set in viewDidload
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

for that you must use `autolayout` and should set proper `constraints` to your label in cell.

Constraint should be in linear chain, I mean your label's top and bottom both constraint must be set and your label should resize according to content so your cell will resize accordingly!

You can refer [Self-sizing Table View Cells by Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) !

Comment: After using this, Its shows only **Title**, DueDate and Description not showing

Answer (score 0):

Put below in viewDidLoad and set autolayout as per below screenshots.

```
  tblview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  tblview.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

[Screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWAvQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWAvQ.png)

[Screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3I5R.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3I5R.png)

[Screenshot [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3FY6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63c5g.png)

[Screenshot [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63c5g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3FY6.png)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using AutoLayout. Have second choice ?