# The appearance of UITableView did not change after updating its height constraint

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I create a QMUITableView which is a subclass of UITableView. I want to make the height of QMUITableView equal to the height of its contentSize.height, so that there is no need to scroll the TableView.

What I have done in the QMUITableView:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.estimatedRowHeight = 50

    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .New, context: nil)        
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    self.viewCH.constant = self.contentSize.height
    print("\(viewCH.constant) \(self.contentSize.height)")
    self.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

the property ViewCH is connected to the height constraint of the tableView. And the print result is as below:

```
viewCH: 100.0 contentSize.height: 100.0
viewCH: 100.0 contentSize.height: 100.0
viewCH: 100.0 contentSize.height: 100.0
viewCH: 112.5 contentSize.height: 112.5
viewCH: 125.0 contentSize.height: 125.0
viewCH: 100.0 contentSize.height: 100.0
viewCH: 112.5 contentSize.height: 112.5
viewCH: 125.0 contentSize.height: 125.0
viewCH: 100.0 contentSize.height: 100.0
viewCH: 133.0 contentSize.height: 133.0
viewCH: 166.0 contentSize.height: 166.0
```

I set the number of rows to be two. we can see that the max contentSize.height is 166 and the viewCH property is always set correctly. However, I observed that the actually height showed on device is 133, it seems that the last update of constraint is not go into effect:

[image]

I think I am not totally understand the layout update process, So I can not figure out the reason and how to fix it, I need some help, thanks!

Comment: Did u call   TABLENAME.reloadData() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888512/tableview-cell-how-do-we-resize-cell-in-swift-along-with-image-and-label/39888662#39888662 Check this

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya , I find that if I do "tableview.reloadData() tableview.layoutIfNeeded()" after the tableview being initialized, for example by a click event or by performselector with a little delay , it works.

Comment: so now your problem solve ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya maybe , but I worry about if this has underlying problem ......

Comment: If you dont mind then show me your controller and storyboard i will give you some batter idea

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  Ok, thanks! but it will sometime, cause it is a small part in a big project. I think I should make a small project.

Comment: ok Make it small demo if in that any problem you face then tell me i will try to solve it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  please look at my demo https://github.com/itenyh/qihuatest.git

Comment: in your demo project only single cell will display . and its cell size default 100.0 and 50.0 why ?

Comment: And tell me that you have 2 cell but its display only one cell not display second cell and your cell size increase automatically,

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  100 and 50 is an estimatedRowHeight. I display two "QMFeedCommentsTbCell" In the first cell of  "QMCommentTbCell", you can see that the two cell is not displayed totally. I am so sorry not reply you immediately, cause I have lots of other work to do. Now I have time to explore this question and it is still important to me!