# How to adjust UITableView's height based on UILabel's height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a `UITableView`. In that I have a single label. I am doing following for label:

1. Set number of lines to zero
2. Set top space to container margin
3. Set bottom space to container margin

My contents for `UILabel` may vary, some time it may have 3 lines, some times 10 lines etc. My problems is it displays only 2 rows. How to adjust the height of cell so that `UILabel` will show the whole contents.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034506/how-to-resize-table-cell-based-on-textview/40035858#40035858 refer this answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39888662/6656894 and also refer this answer @e.k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set numberoflines to 0. Provide either leading & trailing space constraints for your label or fixed width constraint along with top & bottom space constraints. Then use `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: Thank you it works but why should I set estimatedRowHeight?.

Comment: It will calculate your height depending on the autolayout constraints and label size.

Comment: estimatedRowHeight : This will be the minimum height of you row, if AutomaticDimension failed to calculate height then your row height will be set to 44.0

Answer (score 0):

set your label's constraint with cell like top bottom leading and trailing, set number of line for labels to zero and line break mode to word wrap. now  place this two tableView methods to calculate cell height dynamically.

**For Swift 3.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**for Objective C**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

so it will take cell size dynamically as you want.

hope this will help you.